# WP install in sub-dir white screen

Tags: htaccess, directory, installation, wp-config

My WP moved from localhost to online, and now it shows a blank page (wp-admin is working normally). This is the structure: `sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/WP-install`

Something must me off with the redirecting I think after trying these:
- removing all plugins
- activate default template
- change functions.php
- turned on debug mode
- played around with wp-config and .htaccess

[codex.wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) wasn't much helpful either as it, like most posts about this, wants me to place files (like .htaccess) in the root of the site.

The WP install should only be living in the `sub.domain.com/dir1/dir2/WP-install` directory. Because there are other pages above: `sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2` (like a 'site menu').

The `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1/dir2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dir1/dir2/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Another try at the `.htaccess` (**this does display the site, but all the links get duplicated** like: `https://www.sub.domain.nl/sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php`)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Update**

I changed the RewriteBase and RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteBase /internship/avans/
RewriteRule . /internship/avans/index.php [L]
```

Frontpage gets displayed correctly, wp-admin work like before, and **some** page/post links work ?!? Some get the following error (also after clearing cookies):

`Not Found The requested URL /sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php was not found on this server.`

I removed those pages and reposted them, they work fine now. No idea what *this* irregular behavior causes. I checked my DB for wrong updates links as `sub.domain.nl/sub.domain.nl` within phpMyadmin and with Search/Replace, but that seemed not to be the case.

Anyhow, it now works- but I am still wondering what caused some links to work and some of then to reproduce the double links and consequently a Not Found error.

**Update 2**

I ended up using the suggested `.htaccess` by @MrWhite down below:
Read his post for elaboration!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If wp-admin is working without problem, you could try deleting the `htaccess`file and then let WP create it again for you by saving the permalink settings again.

Comment: I tried that: the funny thing is that when I go to permalink settings, delete .htaccess and click update I get kicked out to the login page: https://sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sub.domain.nl%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-permalink.php&reauth=1

Comment: That might have something to do with the WP login cookie. When your cookie (logged in session) and WP stuff don't match anymore, you get kicked out. The same thing happens when you change site url / wp url from http to https. But, does the site work now properly?

Comment: No it does not work, I cant get to re-saving the permalink options. And I also cleared my cookies, log in, do these steps..

Comment: To clarify, there isn't a directory called `/sub.domain.nl` in the document root is there? It's just that I'm wondering how `https://www.sub.domain.nl/sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php` manages to display your site if there isn't?!

Comment: It doesn't. It only shows the front page. The links that go to the doubled URL do not work.

Comment: Have you checked phpmyadmin, to make sure the url pathing is correct?

Comment: What do you mean with url pathing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WordPress is installed in the directory `/dir1/dir2` and the corresponding `.htaccess` file is also in that subdirectory, ie. `/dir1/dir2/.htaccess`, then the `.htaccess` file should look something like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is very similar to the [default WordPress `.htaccess` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), except I have commented out (removed) the `RewriteBase` directive and *removed* the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (ie. what was `/index.php` is now `index.php`). This is important, as it allows Apache to add back the directory-prefix (the location of the `.htaccess` file) at the end of processing.

This obviously means that your URLs must contain the `/dir1/dir2` directory prefix.

---

The two `.htaccess` files you posted don't work because...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.nl$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1/dir2/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir1/dir2/$1
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.nl$
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dir1/dir2/index.php [L]
> ```

This is intended to be placed in the document root `/.htaccess` file with the intention of *hiding* the `/dir1/dir2` subdirectory from the URL. By placing this in `/dir1/dir2/.htaccess` it just won't do anything since the *condition* that checks the `REQUEST_URI` server variable will fail and the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(/)?$` will never match.

> ```
> RewriteBase /sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php [L]
> ```

This would work if `/sub.domain.nl` was a directory on the filesystem (in the URL space), but it's not; it's the hostname, so it doesn't make much sense. This allows the front page (homepage) to be displayed because the first `RewriteRule` prevents further processing. However, sub pages will likely result in an Apache generated 404 as `/sub.domain.nl/dir1/dir2/index.php` does not exist.

Note that, in this example, the `RewriteBase` directive does not do anything. The assigned `RewriteBase` only applies to *relative* path substitutions (ie. not absolute and not root-relative - starting with a slash). There are no relative path substitutions in this example.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I changed the RewriteBase and RewriteRule to:
>
> ```
> RewriteBase /internship/avans/
> RewriteRule . /internship/avans/index.php [L]
> ```

The net result with my version (at the top) is the same. However, the `RewriteBase` directive is redundant and hardcoding the URL-path in this way is superfluous and less portable.

- The `RewriteBase /internship/avans/` directive is redundant in this example (and could be removed), since you have included the full URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. The `RewriteBase` is *only* used when you have a *relative* path substitution (as mentioned above) in order to override the directory-prefix. So, to use the `RewriteBase` in this example you would write this as:

  ```
  RewriteBase /internship/avans/
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
  ```
- Hardcoding the URL-path naturally makes it less portable.
- You only *need* to include the `RewriteBase` *OR* specify the full URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (you don't need to do both) if the `.htaccess` file is not in the application root directory of your WordPress install. eg. If WordPress is installed in `/dir1/dir2`, but the `.htaccess` is in the document root (in order to *hide* the WordPress application directory).

---

Bit of an aside, but... for the reasons mentioned above, the "default" WordPress `.htaccess` file is incorrect/misleading IMO:

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> # END WordPress
> ```

The `RewriteBase /` is not used here since the URL-path (simply `/`) is explicitly included in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*: `/index.php`. You don't need both, and this seems to create a lot of confusion for users. In fact, you don't need either if the `.htaccess` file is in the application root (which it is *most* of the time). By "application root" I'm referring to the directory where WordPress is installed, either the document root, or a subdirectory.

IMO, the "default" WordPress `.htaccess` file should be the one I've modified at the top of my answer (comment out the `RewriteBase` directive and remove the slash prefix) - which is what you are now using. This is far more portable and "just works" without modification regardless of where WordPress is installed (and you probably wouldn't have needed to have asked your question, since the default file would have "just worked").

Comment: As you can read in my update (1) I got it to work. Thank you so much for you elaboration. Could you please explain why my solution or your solution if preferable?

Comment: Glad you got it working - you're welcome. I've updated my answer with more explanation comparing the two versions.